# Reason Behind Passing By reference to a Function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, heap-memory

Here I'm Coding in C++.

```
int main()
{ 
  int setAcapacity = 10;
  int setANOE = 0;
  int *setA;
  createSet(&setA, setAcapacity);
}

void createSet(int **set, int n)
{
*set = new int[n];

}
```

can someone please explain it reason behind passing by reference to createSet Functions..Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `createSet` modify `setA`. for do this it need have pointer of it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Now, concerning the code you show, that code is horrible. I'm not blaming you, but you can't learn from bad examples, so you really need to read a good C++ book. It will explain how and when to use references. Also, the mentioned "pass by reference" is a term from C rather than C++, where it means something slightly different. More reason to get a good book or tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

At first, you do not pass by reference, you pass by pointer!

By reference would look like this:

```
int createSet(int*& set, int n)
//                ^ reference to pointer
{
    set = new int[n]; // assign to referenced value
}

createSet(setA, setAcapacity);
//        ^ no need to take address
```

There are two reasons you would want to pass by reference or pointer:

1. The object to be passed is large, copying would be inefficient. In these cases, you typically pass a `const` reference or pointer to `const`.
2. The object passed shall be modified within the function. This is the case in your example, where a new value is assigned to the pointer `setA` outside the function which is passed via the pointer to named `set`.

Answer (score 0):

What you do in `int createSet(int **set, int n)` you pass a pointer to a pointer; not a reference to a pointer. To pass a reference: `int createSet(int * & set, int n)`.

In case of pass-by-reference, your code would looks like:

```
void createSet(int * & set, int n) // '&' for reference
{
    set = new int[n];
}

int main()
{
    int setAcapacity = 10;
    int setANOE = 0;
    int *setA = nullptr; // Better to initialize
    createSet(setA, setAcapacity);
}
```

For your question: The difference between pass-by-pointer/reference and pass-by-value is that modifications made to arguments passed in by pointer/reference in the called function have effect in the calling function, whereas modifications made to arguments passed in by value in the called function can not affect the calling function. The #value# in your case is: #int-pointer#.

You pass a pointer/reference to the #value# because you want the assignment to target `setA` of the calling function: main(). That's why you also pass, in your original code, the address of `setA`. So `new` can store the new pointer in that address.

In addition, in many cases: Pass-by-references is more efficient than pass-by-value, because it does not copy the arguments. The formal parameter is an alias for the argument. When the called function read or write the formal parameter, it is actually read or write the argument itself.

Comment: "In general: Pass-by-references is more efficient than pass-by-value" Nope, for primitive types, it's usually better to copy them and dodge the indirection, even cache miss bullet in some cases. And for this case specifically, i'd be very surprised if there was much of any efficiency difference in practice.